# Can not start Filezilla 3.15- Ubuntu 16.04-

Tags: 16.04, networking, sftp, filezilla

I tried to upgrade filezilla to 3.20 using the getDeb, installation went fine, but it wouldn't open. 
I went back to 3.15, and the error I get is :

```
    (filezilla:22342): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_widget_set_size_request: assertion 'height >= -1' failed
(filezilla:22342): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_widget_set_size_request: assertion 'width >= -1' failed
(filezilla:22342): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_widget_set_size_request: assertion 'height >= -1' failed
(filezilla:22342): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_widget_set_size_request: assertion 'width >= -1' failed
(filezilla:22342): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_widget_set_size_request: assertion 'width >= 1' failed
(filezilla:22342): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_widget_set_size_request: assertion 'height >= -1' failed
(filezilla:22342): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_widget_set_size_request: assertion 'width >= -1' failed
(filezilla:22342): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_widget_set_size_request: assertion 'height >= -1' failed
(filezilla:22342): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_widget_set_size_request: assertion 'height >= -1' failed
(filezilla:22342): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_widget_set_size_request: assertion 'height >= -1' failed
(filezilla:22342): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_widget_set_size_request: assertion 'height >= -1' failed
wxD-Bus: Signal from /org/freedesktop/DBus, member NameAcquired
wxD-Bus: Reply with serial 2
wxD-Bus: Reply to RegisterClient, our object path is /org/gnome/SessionManager/Client21
wxD-Bus: Unregistered
```

I tried removing fiezilla in config, removed the last local directory, but the error didn't go away.
The problem is that no matter what filezilla opens, but as soon as I click connect to servers it aborts.

I checked all dependencies [Dependencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ydaDG.png).

I'd appreciate it if someone can help.

This is the output of apt-cache policy filezilla filezilla-common:

```
filezilla:
  Installed: 3.15.0.2-1ubuntu1
  Candidate: 3.15.0.2-1ubuntu1
  Version table:
 *** 3.15.0.2-1ubuntu1 500
        500 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
filezilla-common:
  Installed: 3.15.0.2-1ubuntu1
  Candidate: 3.15.0.2-1ubuntu1
  Version table:
 *** 3.15.0.2-1ubuntu1 500
        500 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages
        500 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

I ignored getdeb, and went back to 3.15 version, but that's the one that aborts after clicking connect. And when it aborts I get this message on terminal:

```
filezilla: symbol lookup error: filezilla: undefined symbol: _ZN2fz6threadC2Ev
```

Comment: Drop getdeb, they brake many packages. I'm talking this seriously. I have had problems with hexchat and filezilla. Please update your question with output of `apt-cache policy filezilla filezilla-common`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71880/discussion-between-sudodus-and-noosh).

Comment: If ***you*** know how to make Filezilla work in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, please chip in and help :-)